# What is the "malevolent force" that left my armor?

Tags: brogue

I was cruising along (read: waiting as I regained health) and it suddenly said `A malevolent force leaves your plate armor`.

What does this mean?

Maybe it auto-uncursed? The plate armor was strength 19, and I enchanted it once (now 18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The armor was [cursed](http://brogue.wikia.com/wiki/Cursed) before you had enchanted it. A cursed item cannot be unequipped and will often have a negative enchantment value on it.

[Enchanting](http://brogue.wikia.com/wiki/Scroll_of_Enchanting) cursed armor or weapons will remove any curse on it.

I'm not too sure as to the cause of the delay you experienced. As far as I know, any curse is removed immediately upon enchanting the item. (Perhaps the item got cursed again, and the curse was removed by an effect such as [negation](http://brogue.wikia.com/wiki/Negation)? This wouldn't explain the reduced strength requirement as negation resets enchantments, so you might have run into a bug.)

Comment: Okay. This wasn't right after the enchantment though. Is that still the same?

Comment: No. The item is no longer cursed. As far as I know, items do not uncurse themselves.

Comment: Why was the delay there then? It was a full level after. (exploring the whole thing)

Comment: Really odd—might have been item identification delay. Then again, as far as I know, items don't ID themselves until you've worn them for a period of time, and you'd know on equip if the item was cursed. Not too sure what happened there. (Maybe a bug?)